# Content Type drop-down missing on editform.aspx for a list

Tags: 2010, list, form

by default, editform.aspx is supposed to include a drop-down that allows the content type for a particular list item to be changed.

I am using the default form on a list and noticed that the drop-down isn't included.

Is anyone aware of a method for adding it to the form?

Comment: How many content types do you have configured for this list?

Answer (score 1):

[Content Type Change Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434692%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is used for selection of [content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contenttype.aspx) in form. It is rendered if the following conditions are met:

- rendering mode for form is *Edit* [Control Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.formcomponent.controlmode.aspx)
- [SPList.ContentTypesEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.contenttypesenabled.aspx) is *True*. To do this in the user interface, select *List Settings*, and then select *Advanced Settings*. Under *Allow management of content types*, click Yes. For more details follow [Site and List Content Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463016%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- the amount of available [content types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contenttype.aspx) for List should be more 1